# How to bind a key in sublime text 2?

Tags: 14.04, sublime-text

I want to open preferences and add a key:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+r"], "command": "reindent" , "args": { "single_line": false }}
```

How to find my sublime and stop errors for adding this to wrong directories. I have fresh sublime text 2 install. What steps are for adding this key to sublime text 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking to add your personal key bindings? If so check `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User`. The file format is the same as `Key Bindings - Default` and it won't be overwritten by Sublime Text updates.